# C# - Lock not working but Volatile AND Lock does?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, semaphore

I am trying to poll an API as fast and as efficiently as possible to get market data. The API allows you to get market data from *batchSize* markets per request. The API allows you to have 3 concurrent requests but no more (or throws errors).

I may be requesting data from many more than *batchSize* different markets.

I continuously loop through all of the markets, requesting the data in batches, one batch per thread and 3 threads at any time.

The total number of markets (and hence batches) can change at any time.

I'm using the following code:

```
private static object lockObj = new object();

private void PollMarkets()
{
    const int NumberOfConcurrentRequests = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfConcurrentRequests; i++)
    {
        int batch = 0;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {    
            while (true)
            {
                if (markets.Count > 0)
                {
                    List<string> batchMarketIds;

                    lock (lockObj)
                    {
                        var numBatches = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)markets.Count / batchSize);
                        batchMarketIds = markets.Keys.Skip(batch*batchSize).Take(batchSize).ToList();
                        batch = (batch + 1) % numBatches;
                    }

                    var marketData = await GetMarketData(batchMarketIds);

                    // Do something with marketData

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000); // wait for some markets to be added.
                    }
                }
            }
       });
    }
}
```

Even though there is a lock in the critical section, each thread starts with batch = 0 (each thread is often polling for duplicate data).

If I change batch to a private volatile field the above code works as I want it to (volatile and lock).

So for some reason my lock doesn't work? I feel like it's something obvious but I'm missing it.

I believe that it is best here to use a lock instead of a volatile field, is this also correct?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. I don't understand what isn't clear. You're sharing a variable between multiple threads, and you say `volatile` solves your problem.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov volatile + lock solves the problem, but I believe a lock alone should be enough?

Comment: Where is lockObj defined?

Comment: @JamesBrierley Added lockObj definition

Comment: Does it work if you define batch outside the for loop?

Comment: Is the history of the processed markets required?

Comment: What does it means "batch = (batch + 1) % numBatches;"?

Comment: @JamesBrierley That fixed it, wow... Amateur Hour! Post as an answer and I'll mark as best.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh Thanks for your help, it's just looping through the list in batches.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is a bug "batch = (batch + 1) % numBatches;" in my mind be careful.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh I want it to take batches from a list of marketIds, loop through the entire list and start again from the start. I think that's the correct way to do that (modulus arithmetic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that you were defining the batch variable inside the for loop.  That meant that the threads were using their own variable instead of sharing it.

Comment: Why declaring `volatile` solved the problem, then? (or maybe it didn't, really..)

Comment: @shay__ The variable definition would have to have been moved to be volatile.  You can't declare a local variable as volatile.

Comment: @JamesBrierley sorry, I don't understand... If the real problem was that every thread had it's own batch variable, then why declaring `lockObj` as volatile solved the problem? What `lockObj` has to do with anything? Perhaps it didn't really 'solved' the problem.

Comment: @shay__ I was declaring the batch variable as a volatile field (external to the method).

Comment: @Watson oh, sorry... I thought it was lockObj variable :)

Answer (score 1):

In my mind you should use Queue<> to create a jobs pipeline.

Something like this

```
private int batchSize = 10;
private Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();

private void AddMarket(params int[] marketIDs)
{
    lock (queue)
    {
        foreach (var marketID in marketIDs)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(marketID);
        }

        if (queue.Count >= batchSize)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(queue);
        }
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    for (var tid = 0; tid < 3; tid++)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                List<int> toProcess;

                lock (queue)
                {
                    if (queue.Count < batchSize)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(queue);
                        continue;
                    }

                    toProcess = new List<int>(batchSize);
                    for (var count = 0; count < batchSize; count++)
                    {
                        toProcess.Add(queue.Dequeue());
                    }

                    if (queue.Count >= batchSize)
                    {
                        Monitor.Pulse(queue);
                    }
                }

                var marketData = await GetMarketData(toProcess);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would be ideal if I only needed to get each market once (using a queue and popping off when complete). I have to iterate over the list of markets in batches and poll each one until the market closes (then remove from list).